# Htaccess w/ Wordpress: rewrite specific path to root domain but keep full path

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want

```
http://example.com/foo-bar
```

to display the webpage from

```
http://example.com/
```

but retain `/foo-bar` in the address bar. I know it appears as a duplicate of many `RewriteRule` questions asked here, but none of which I tried retained the first URL in the address bar; they were simple 301/302 redirects.

What I have in .htaccess right now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com)$
RewriteRule ^foo-bar http://example.com [NC,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Is this only possible with proxies or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, you need to *internally rewrite* the request, not *externally redirect* (301/302). No "proxies" are required. You are almost there with what you have, except that when you specify an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` substitution Apache will implicitly trigger an external redirect (despite the docs suggesting that if the domain matches the current host it should be stripped - it doesn't do this in .htaccess in my experience).

Try something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo-bar$ index.html [L]
```

Unless you are serving mutliple domains then you probably don't need the `RewriteCond` directive? (The `NC` flag here is simply a security measure to catch malformed requests.)

I appended a `$` (end of string) anchor on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to make it an exact match for "foo-bar" and not a URL that *starts* "foo-bar". The *substitution* should reference your DirectoryIndex document (`index.html`, `index.php`, or whatever document is loaded by default in the document root). I've removed the `NC` flag, unless you specifically need a case-insensitive match?

> **UPDATE:** There actually are some Wordpress ...

Ah, WordPress is the "problem" here. In fact, WP already rewrites *all* requests through `index.php` in the document root, so these new directives (to "rewrite specific path to root domain but keep full path") are entirely redundant.

WP then uses the URL (the visible path in the address bar) ie. "/foo-bar" in this case, to route the request. Unless "/foo-bar" is defined as a valid URL in WP itself then WP is going to generate a 404 Not Found.

This is something you need to configure in WP itself, not .htaccess.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing the last two lines with the above code removed the redirect altogether.

Comment: Try replacing the `RewriteRule` substitution (a single slash) with the actual directory index document (eg. `index.php` or `index.html`, etc.) - I've updated my answer. Also, remove the `RewriteCond` directive altogether if it's not required, as mentioned above - this is only required if you are hosting multiple domains. These directives should go _before_ any other internal rewrites, but probably _after_ any other _external redirects_ in your .htaccess file - the order to directives in the Apache config file are important.

Comment: That changed nothing either. There actually are some Wordpress defaults in the htaccess as I edited my question but adding your code before or after the if module doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately WordPress is the "problem" - I've updated my answer. "...the above code removed the redirect altogether." - what did you actually mean by this? I assume you are seeing a WordPress generated 404 page?

Comment: A 404 page, exactly.

Comment: How about altering the RewriteCond in the WordPress block to overlook `/foo-bar`?

Comment: ...and not rewrite `/foo-bar` at all? What page are you wanting to display at `/foo-bar`? Presumably you want the WordPress home page located at the URL `http://example.com/` to display? In order to display a WP page (that's stored in the database) you need to go through `index.php`, which means rewriting the URL at some point (or _redirecting_) and configuring WP to understand `/foo-bar`. If, however, you wanted to display an independent webpage, outside of WP, then yes you could write an exception into the WP code block - although you probably wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: (Just to add, I don't think it's necessarily a good idea to modify the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments, since WP itself likes to manage this block of code. ?)